# How to replace every character in a field to a single character (but with the same length of text)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to update a column that has the value "something nice" to "X", but the result must contain the exact number of characters as the original. Spaces must be ignored. I tried using `PATINDEX` but without success.

I tried replace with patindex and left, right, looking in some other examples not so similar to mine, but without success.

Some original outputs:

```
something nice
hello
I am good and you
```

And how it is expected to be:

```
XXXXXXXXX XXXX
XXXXX
X XX XXXX XXX XXX
```

Comment: What about characters such as comma, colons, quotes etc?

Comment: Aside: E. A. Poe has been there: [X'ING A PARAGRAB](https://www.eapoe.org/works/tales/xingc.htm).

Comment: @StringTheory all the characters must be replaced. There are other things like "Date time" should be DD/MM/YYYY and so on but I think the first thing is try to use RegEx or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance is important ***DO NOT*** use a scalar function as they crush performance. Grab a copy of [PatReplace8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/patreplace8k) and it's pretty simple:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = 
'something nice
hello
I am good and you';

SELECT NewString FROM dbo.PatReplace8k(@string,'[a-zA-Z]','X');
```

**Results:**

```
XXXXXXXXX XXXX
XXXXX
X XX XXXX XXX XXX
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `TRANSLATE()` and `REPLICATE()` functions as

```
SELECT Str,
       TRANSLATE(Str, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', REPLICATE('X', 26))
FROM
(
  VALUES
  ('something nice, hello, I am good and you')
) T(Str)
```

---

*UPDATE:*

Since you're on 2012 version, you can create your own function as

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ReplaceChars
(
  @String NVARCHAR(300)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(300)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Str NVARCHAR(300) = @String;

  SELECT @Str = REPLACE(@Str, CHAR(Number), 'X')
  FROM Master..spt_values --Tally table
  WHERE [Type] = 'P'
        AND
        Number BETWEEN 65 AND 90;
  RETURN(@Str);
END;
```

Then use it as

```
SELECT dbo.ReplaceChars(Str)
FROM
(
  VALUES
  ('something nice, hello, I am good and you'),
  ('Another String.')
) T(Str)
```

**[Online Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=40e7778ee3e8c26f1807944a96aff5a1)**

Comment: I am sorry but my SQL Server version is 2012 SP3

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server 2017 and that you could have characters other than A-z (that need replacing), then one idea using [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2):

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int IDENTITY,
                            SomeString varchar(100));

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (SomeString)
VALUES ('something nice'),
       ('hello'),
       ('I am good and you');

GO

SELECT YT.ID,STRING_AGG(V.S,' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber) AS NewString
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(YT.SomeString,' ') DS
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLICATE('X',LEN(DS.Item))))V(S)
GROUP BY YT.ID;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

If you aren't using SQL Server 2017, you'll need to replace `STRING_AGG` with the "older" method of created a delimited list: `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH`.

As mentioned, if you are using SQL Server 2012 or prior, then use `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH`:

```
SELECT YT.ID,
       STUFF((SELECT ' ' + V.S
              FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(YT.SomeString,' ') DS
                   CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLICATE('X',LEN(DS.Item))))V(S)
              ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(100)'),1,1,'') AS NewString
FROM dbo.YourTable YT;
```

Comment: I am sorry but my SQL Server version is 2012 SP3. I will take a look in this "DelmitedSplit8K"

Comment: Any reason you haven't updated to SP4(GDR), @Killer?

Comment: Have also added a 2012 version.

Comment: @Lamu it is not up to me, v2012 is really old. Thanks, I will test it now

Comment: 2012 is still supported though (althougg only in extended) and plenty still use it (including myself in some instances). My question was why it's running an old SP; when SP4-GDR came out June 2017 (over 2 years ago) and the GDR patch was early last year. It strongly implies your server is patched against the latest **known** vulnerabilities such as Spectre and meltdown, @Killer